# Can a Transformer with Current Production Methods Last until the Heat Death of the Universe?

Tags: vacuum-tube, lifetime, manufacturing-process, durability, cathode-ray-oscilloscope

Transformers have no moving parts in direct contact with other solids, do not rely on non-reversible chemical reactions, and do not rely on nuclear reactions. So, with inert materials, the atomic bonds that make up the transformers should theoretically never change after it is manufactured.

As far as I know, commercially produced power transformers age because their insulation between the sets of windings is made of kraft paper (primarily cellulose) and their coolant is made of mineral oil. Both consist of complex organic molecules, which not only are reducing agents strong enough to be used as a fuel in the presence of an oxidizer, but also chemically self-decompose over time. That is further made worse by water ingress into the coolant as the seals (made of rubber) degrade over time. Also, unlike in thermionic/incandescent filaments or integrated circuits, the current density in a transformer winding is low enough that electromigration should be too small to even be measured by electron microscopes.

So, under current design and manufacturing methods, how long can a mass-produced electrical power transformer be realistically made to last at rated load without maintenance? Under the given conditions of

1. that transformer is made entirely of inorganic chemicals that are inert with each other,
2. all atoms that comprise the transformer are stable isotopes,
3. there are no design or manufacturing defects,
4. the coolant never comes into contact with an oxidizing agent,
5. the transformer is not damaged or destroyed, and
6. the power supply stops outputting power when the last brown dwarf becomes a black dwarf,
   will the transformer last at full-load rating until the Heat Death of the Universe?

Comment: Magnetic domains move so no, transformers do not have no moving parts. Electrons also move and, will produce finite amounts of wear.

Comment: Or you might simply ask the manufacturer if the part has a MTBF rating.

Comment: it would be better to ask in the community for Physics.